# scrollTop if screen is less than 480px

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, scrolltop, smooth-scrolling

I have a responsive horizontal scrolling website.
I used a smooth scroll script so when I click on a link in the navigation bar it will scroll smoothly to it's anchor.
The problem is that when the screen is less than 480px, it becomes vertical. I tried to use this script but it doesnt work:

```
            $(function() {
            $('nav#main a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                if (screen.width >= 480) {
                   $('html, body').stop().animate({
                       scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                   }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                } else {
                   $('html, body').stop().animate({
                       scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                   }, 1000);
                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });
```

Any idea whats wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, could not get you...

Comment: In short - I need the smooth scroll to work horizontally when the screen is more than 480px and vertically when the screen is less than 480px.

Comment: ummm, got it, wrap your code inside the window resize handler, then you would get exactly...

Comment: How do I do it? I'm a bit new to it..

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){//your code here});

Comment: It doesnt seem to work.. do I need to put the code exactly as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use match media

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) { 
}
else
{ 
}
```

[Match Media Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)

Comment: You mean something like this?

$(function() {
 $('nav#main a').bind('click',function(event){
 var $anchor = $(this);
 if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) { 
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
 scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
 }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
 }
 else
 {
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
 scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
 }, 1000); 
 }
 event.preventDefault();
 });
});

Comment: (min-width: 480px) means the window is more than 480 px
if you use (max-width: 480px) instead, means the window is less than 480px

Comment: Ok, but how do I implement the code inside match media?